# Overwrite Frame with other Frame after comparing

Tags: python, pandas

2 Frames and I want the 2nd Frame to "overwrite"/update the 1st Frame. Basically, where Table1-colB-value = Table2-oldB-value, overwrite Table1-colB-value with Table2-newB-value.

Table1

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Z |
| 4 | W |
| 5 | X |
| 6 | X |
| 7 | W |

Table2

| oldB | newB |
| --- | --- |
| X | L |
| Y | M |
| Z | N |
| W | O |

Admired result after overwriting:

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | L |
| 2 | M |
| 3 | N |
| 4 | O |
| 5 | L |
| 6 | L |
| 7 | O |

Is something like that possible? I did something similar using `replace`, but comparing 2 frames would be way better, e.g. in case the new-value-input-frame changes you wouldn't have to adjust the replace-code at every respective point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this, a fast way would be to convert your df2 to `dict`, using oldB column as your keys, and then `map`it on your colB in df1:

```
d = dict(zip(df2.oldB, df2.newB))
df1['new_colB'] = df1['colB'].map(d)
```

Will get back

```
   colA colB new_colB
0     1    X        L
1     2    Y        M
2     3    Z        N
3     4    W        O
4     5    X        L
5     6    X        L
6     7    W        O
```

**EDIT**: I have added a P in colB of `df1` to illustrate.

You can pretty much do the same process, just wrap it in `np.where()`, and set the condition like below, or use `fillna()` to fill the `nulls` with 'colB'

```
# Using np.where
import numpy as np
df1['new_colB'] = np.where(df1['colB'].map(d).isnull(),df1['colB'],df1['colB'].map(d))

# Using fillna()
df1['new_colB'] = (df1['colB'].map(d)).fillna(df1['colB'])
```

I would go for 2nd option because the first one map's twice.

Both will give you:

```
df1
   colA colB new_colB
0     1    X        L
1     2    Y        M
2     3    Z        N
3     4    W        O
4     5    X        L
5     6    X        L
6     7    W        O
7     8    P        P
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it definitely helped me. Let's say colB contains a value, which is non-existant in the dict. For Example P. According to pandas docu it then converts to NaN. Can I avoid that? So it keeps the P

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your new request. Thanks.

Comment: do I understand it correctly that its not possible to ensure this in the first map - function? I have to "refill the empty cells" afterwards?